# RepeatButton TouchDown

Tags: .net, button, touch, repeat, repeatbutton

I have a repeatbutton that updates an integer in a textbox by 5. This works well with the mouse. When trying this on the touchscreen, the event doesn't get repeated even though I can see via the style that the button is still down.

I tried handling the TouchDown event because I assumed that it must be the result of the difference between a RoutedEventArgs and TouchEventArgs. This did not provide a continuous firing of the event either. Interestingly though, it did fire both the MouseDOwn and TouchDown events resulting in an increase of 10.

How do I get a repeatbutton to repeat on a touchscreen?

Comment: Platform/framework/language? Looks like .NET, but can't be sure.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Yes, it is .Net Framework 4. Responses in C# or VB.Net or XAML would be fine.